# How can I implement an easy CAPTCHA in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, next.js, captcha

I created my own website using next.js and react. Since I live in Germany and must follow GDPR (EU General Data Protection Regulation) I need an alternative to google reCaptcha to protect my Contact form and Comment Forms against bots. I searched a lot but unfortunately, I could not find any cost free alternative to google reCaptcha...

So I thought about implementing my own rather "simplistic" captcha solution in which I would randomly generate some numbers and ask a simple math question.Additionally, I would implement some honey pots in the form to misslead bots.

It should work fine for my small website, but I have no idea how to validate form input data (math question and honey pot fields) on the backend site of next.js.

My question is:
How can I implement a simple captcha solution (like: please answer the following question: what is x+y? ) using next.js?

Comment: It's off topic but...I don't see how Google reCaptcha is not compatible with GDPR since its used in many high profile European sites.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @djones when using Google reCaptcha die IP Adress of the user is directed to the Google’s service which is in the USA. Given the GDPR all user data must stay within EU. You can use a cookie and service consent tool to have the allowance of the user for google Recaptcha service. When the user accepts it, you can activate and use Google reCaptcha. That’s how the big companies do it. But for a rather small website it would be a overkill and also make it user experience less fun (I hate those consent popups). Therefore I would like to find another solution